# Remove specific files

Tags: linux, bash

In this directory `/home/Scrivania/pdb_files`, I have a list of files with the same filename format, `XXX_?.pdb`.

For example,

```
A4R_A.pdb 
A4R_B.pdb
A4R_C.pdb
TY6_A.pdb
001_A.pdb
001_B.pdb
ATE_B.pdb
```

I need to keep only some of these files and remove others. In particular, if I have multiple files that have the first three characters of the name identical, I would like to keep only one, regardless of the last character, "`?`".

So at the end, in my directory, I should have only these files:

```
A4R_A.pdb 
TY6_A.pdb
001_A.pdb
ATE_B.pdb
```

and remove these: `A4R_B.pdb`, `A4R_C.pdb`, `001_B.pdb`

It is not critical which of the files with the first three equal characters is retained (`A`, `B` or `C`). Also, there might be other cases where the character "`?`" is not a letter, but a number, or maybe is a letter different to A, B or C.

So the selection must be based exclusively on the first three characters. For example, one strategy is to keep, for more files with the first three equal characters, only the first file you come across.

Could someone suggest a script in bash that can do this?

Comment: Well, since the suffix to be kept doesn't matter, you could simply `rename` all files to the same name but removing the `_?` part with overwriting. This would leave you with `A4R.pdb A4R.pdb 001.pdb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
for dup in $(ls  *.pdb | awk 'BEGIN{FS="_"}{if (++dup[$1] >= 2) print}')
do
   rm -f $dup; 
done
```

- `FS="_"` to keep underscore as field separator.
- `(++dup[$1] >= 2)` will print the full file name if the counter is greater than or equal to 2, only those inputs will be passed to the `for` loop to remove the file

Comment: I know the sample files would not suffer from it, but parsing Ls automatically triggers [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 1):

You can execute this after changing to your directory in question. It will keep the first alphabetically file for each occurence of the first 3 letters.

```bsh
printf "%s\n" ???_?.pdb | awk -F_ 'seen[$1]++' | xargs echo rm --
```

Remove `echo` after testing. The above `awk` command filters only filenames that have the same first 3 letters with a previous one, so it allows them to pass for deletion.

Comment: Great use of Awk, but this needs to be used cautiously. It solves the problem for the sample files, but breaks for files that contain spaces, for example.

Comment: Yes, the GNU "space-version" could be `printf "%s\0" ???_?.pdb | awk -F_ -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\0' 'seen[$1]++' | xargs -0 echo rm --`. (seems not necessary here).